# Showing suggestions in a text box in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a text box where user will type his region's name and I have show him some options based on his typing. I am making a api call to get the possible data. The api is written in nodejs. I am using bootstrap.typeahed to show the possible suggestions. I am making the api call whenever the user types a letter. This is done but I am facing a problem if the user is typing very fast. Then the api calls are not returning in the same order they were called, so the user is sometimes seeing wrong data. How to prevent this? In angular can I reject a api call if a later api call is already over?

Comment: Pretty common issue, try to delay the update of your ng-model by debouncing it using ng-model options. Here is the documentation - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)  and set the `debounce` to call the api on timer expires.
If someone is typing quickly, it will capture more than one letter and at a slower pace one letter at a time. This will give a drop of space so there are no mixups. If the delay is a short one, it will move smoothly with no noticable delay.

Add this to attribute to your element
`ng-model-options="{ debounce: 400 }"`

Comment: Looks like it has improved the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @decon please mark as correct answer if this helped. thanks

Comment: Yes sure. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ng-model-options` to add a delay when model changes.

```
<input ng-model="model" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 700, 'blur': 0 }}"></input>
```